# How to send packet another server using dpdk?

Tags: dpdk

My question is how to send packet another Physical Server from my Computer using dpdk.

I already watched example code rxtx_callbacks and i want to use this code.
but there is no place to enter a specific ip and port to another server.

**how i can send packets to places on a server using dpdk with specified ip and port?
and how i can receive packets using dpdk?**

Is l3fwd correct or is this another concept?

help me

Comment: requesting to please rephrase your question for clarity. As `how i can send packets to places on a server` can mean you are `intending to use packet within the server` or `send the packet out of server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DPDK is an open-source library that allows one to bypass Kernel and ETH-IP-TCP stack to send packets from userspace directly on NIC or other custom hardware. There are multiple examples and projects like `pktgen` and `TREX` which uses to generate user-defined packets (desired MAC address, VLAN, IP and TCP-UDP) payload.

For the queries

1. **how i can send packets to places on a server using dpdk with specified ip and port?**

[Answer] make use of [DPDK PKTGEN](https://pktgen-dpdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as an easy way to generate. Other examples are [pcap based burst replay](https://doc.dpdk.org/burst-replay/) and [trex](https://trex-tgn.cisco.com/).

But the easiest way to generate and send traffic is using `scapy` with DPDK sample application `skeleton`. Following are the steps required to achieve the same.

- Install DPDK to desired platform (preferably Linux)
- build the DPDK example skeleton found in path `[dpdk root folder]/examples/skeleton`
- bind a physical NIC (if traffic needs to be send out of server) with userspace drivers like igb_uio, uio_pci_generic or vfio-pci
- start the application with options '-l 1 --vdev=net_tap0,iface=scapyEth'. this will create TAP interface with name ***scapyEth***.
- using scapy now create your custom packet with desired MAC, VLAN, IP and Port numbers.

**and how i can receive packets using dpdk?**

[Answer] on receiver side run DPDK application like testpmd, l2fwd, or skeleton if packets needs to received by Userspace DPDK application or any Linux sockets can receive the UDP packets.

Note: easiest way to check whether packets are received is to run ***tcpudmp***. example `tcpdump -eni eth1 -Q in` (where eth1 is physical interface on Reciever Server.

Note: Since the request `how i can send packets to places on a server` is not clear

1. Using DPDK one can send packets through a physical interface using dedicated NIC, FPGA and wireless devices
2. DPDK can send packets among applications using memif interface
3. DPDK can send packets between VM using virtio and vhost
4. DPDK can send and receive packets to kernel, where Kernel routing stack and ARP table determine which kernel interface will forward the packets.

Comment: @Leftddr if you find the answer useful please accept

Comment: i bind physical NIC with userspace driver 'mlx5_core' because i use Mellanox but i can't generate dpdk.  Is this same for mlx5_core driver and other driver?

Comment: @Leftddr I do not have access to mlx5 adapter, I have X710, E810, X522, i350 in the above mentioned steps I am able to generate packets. Requesting to open a new question with appropriate information as your question is related to vendor specific nic